# How to move items around in canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have an Android program that creates a graph.  It is a fullscreen coordinate system with all of the drawing being done in Canvas. So how can I move the view around on Touch (up, down, left, right, zoom in, zoom out)?

Answer (score 0):

You want to recieve TouchEvents from the screen, and use them to alter the location (and size for zooming) of the image you're drawing. [Tutorial on dragging images on Canvas.](http://obviam.net/index.php/displaying-graphics-with-android/)

If you get the first onTouchEvent (DOWN), compare this with other Events (MOVE).

I.e. `deltaX = initialX - event.getX();`
then you move your bitmap the amount of `deltaX`.